# Custom UITableViewCell built using IB resizing?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, autosize

I have ensured the autosizing mask of my cell allows flexible width, but when the device is rotated the Cells are not resized.

I have also verified the tableview is resized, the problem is directly with the cells.

This is the code I am using to create the cells:

```
if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MetaTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

Can someone think of what might be wrong?

Are cells created using IB not resized ever?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the cell itself that is not getting resized; as opposed to some content in the cell?

Comment: I have tested this by removing everything from the cell and displaying it. It still does not resize.

Comment: If there's nothing in the cell, how do you know where the cells are? Are these grouped or plain style? To the best of my knowledge, you can never control the width of a table cell; it is always just whatever the table itself is

Comment: I test with just the label on the cell, and just to clarify, I am having trouble changing the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its the height of the cell that is not resized I suggest you to modify the `UITableView` delegate method after rotation.

-

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(condition)// has rotation taken place
    // new height
    else
    // old height
    }
```

Pls make sure that you call `[tableView reloadData];` when rotation has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you want to change the height of UITableViewCells, right? Try adding this line in your TableView's delegate:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return *height*;
}
```

I was having the same problem. If you set the size in IB, you can put more stuff in there, but it will still ask your delegate for the height when loading. If your delegate does not implement this method, it will simply take the default height.