# How can I add name and quantity in a single row in a table view?

Tags: iphone

I am creating a simple shopping list application, and with it I am displaying an array of items.

[image: ArrayOfitems]

How can I display quantity of each item after its name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could us a formatted string for this. Instead of setting the labels value to just the name, do it like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%i)", yourNameVariable, quantity]
```

**Edit_:** If alignment is not a problem, you can go this way, otherwise use @7KV7 solution

Comment: This might result in something unpleasant to the user as the alignment will be a problem. The quantity field will be displayed in different positions based on the name of the item.

Comment: Commodities with small name will have quantity near them that somewhere close to the middle of the cell whereas it will be to right end if the name of commodity is large

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a custom `UITableViewCell` which will enable you to display the cell with contents the way you want it to. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332136/custom-uitableviewcell-built-using-ib-resizing/5349953#5349953) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the UITableViewCellStyle in cellForRowAtIndexpath as UITableViewCellStyleValue1 or UITableViewCellStyleValue2 and can access two labels in a row as shown in below images....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.

return cell;
```

}

In all these cell styles, the larger of the text labels is accessed via the textLabel property and the smaller via the detailTextLabel property.

[image]

for more click [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using custom table view cells. You can check [this](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/) tutorial out, for help

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to create a customized UITableViewCell

```
-(UITableViewCell*)customCell
{
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier]; 


    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);    
    UILabel *itemNameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];

    itemNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    itemNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    CGRect anotherLabelFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    UILabel *quantityLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:anotherLabelFrame] autorelease];

    quantityLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    quantityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:itemNameLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:quantityLabel];

    return cell;

}
```

OR

You can Subclass the UITableViewCell and use it.

Comment: call this method in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath